# Function to change path with cd input

Tags: python

If I am given a path ("C:\Users\Meow\Desktop"), how do I get a relative path from a user’s normal cd input? For example:
func("C:\Users\Meow\Desktop","../../")
returns "C:\Users"

And other similar things. Basically simulating the behaviour of a cd command on Windows, without access to that specified file system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
os.path.normpath(os.path.join("C:\\Users\\Meow\\Desktop","../../"))
```

Note that the `\` in the first path needs to be escaped, i.e. `\\`.

Comment: Didn’t seem to work, it changes my whole path to ".."

Comment: Tried again to confirm. It was the windows file separators screwing with something. Gonna try replacing them with unix file separators

Comment: Oh wait, the problem is the `\ ` in the string for the first path. Those need to be escaped.  I just modified my answer, try it now.

Comment: It’s working okay, though "cd /" does not bring me to C:, and "cd C:" brings me to "\C:"

Comment: Nah, it was already escaped. But the C: thing is solveable with some hardcoding. The solution works okayish for something that isn’t too critical. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Note a raw string literal is more fun then a bunch of escapes (`r'my\string\with\backslashes'`).

Comment: Ah. I’m passing in input, the path itself isn’t a static hardcoded thing, so I didn’t meet that problem. Never saw a raw string used before though, interesting.